# display mongo installation path

Tags: javascript, mongodb

For some reason I can't find where Mongo is install on in mint.

How can you display the path for mongodb.

I have tried

mongodb v

Of course this only displayed the version.

Answer (score 1):

When you are searching a file in your filesystem while you are running Mint a very easy way to find it is to do the following:

1. Search for the corresponding file (super quick):

   ```
   locate '*mongo*.conf'
   ```